# How do I log every output from a PHP script from the command line?

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, command-line-interface

I'm running a PHP script and want to log all output from the program to a single log file via the command line. This is what I'm doing now when I execute the script.

```
php generate_production_persons.php 1 10000 2>&1 > log
```

Error/Notice/Etc. messages don't redirect to my `log` file. They still just output to the screen where the script is running.

I don't want to log from within my script. I just want to be able to write all of this to a log file whenever I run a PHP script from the command line. I want the output in the `log` file to look exactly as it looks from the CLI where it's running had I not redirected the output to a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do the trick

```
php generate_production_persons.php 1 10000 > everything.log 2>&1
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain what it's doing, as I seem to have my logic reversed/confused.

Comment: you are telling the script to write to your log by using `>` and then `2` is saying that `stderr` should be output in the same location as `1` the `stdout`.  that being said you can do things like `> transaction.log 2> errors.log` to separate out your output, or even `>> transaction.log 2>> errors.log` which will append to the files instead of overwriting them.

Comment: And how would you save to a *local* file if youre running php scripts in ssh?